# Is there any way to force the Options Menu to be shown on Android

Tags: android

I want to show the options menu of an Activity to be displayed on an event. This is the menu that is shown on click of the Menu button on the handset.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

for open menu on any event so u need add this code in even

```
openOptionsMenu();
```